# Using jquery for related selects - how to clear the 2nd select when 1st changes?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 related selects - state and school name.  In my HTML, if I do this for the 2nd select:

```
<select name="school" id="school">
 <option value=''></option>
</select>
```

When the state changes, the user still has to click the select to see the schools (i.e. it doesn't populate that first element).

If I remove the option tag:

```
<select name="school" id="school">

</select>
```

I get the first school to show up automatically, but when I change states, the first school remains stuck.

I've tried this inside my onChange before the ajax:

```
$('#schoolSelect').empty();
```

The select is built here:

```
function(results,status,xhr){ 
   var $schoolSelect= $('#school');
   $schoolSelect.find('option:not(:first)').remove();
   if (results.length){ 
    $.each (results, function(i){ 
       $schoolSelect.append('<option value="' + results[i].CO_COID + '">' + results[i].CO_NAME + '</option>'); 
    }); 
   }
```

Ideally the list would start empty and then the first value would change as the first select was changed.  If no schools are in that state it would revert back to blank.

Comment: `#schoolSelect` does not match `#school`.  Are you trying to clear a different element?

Comment: `$schoolSelect[0].options.length=1` would also remove all but this first

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tips above I solved it by doing this:

```
<select name="school" id="school">

</select>
```

And then in jquery add one line:

```
function(results,status,xhr){ 
  var $schoolSelect= $('#school');
    $schoolSelect.find('option:not(:first)').remove();
    if (results.length){ 
      $('#school').empty(); //clears the 2nd drop down
      $.each (results, function(i){ 
      $schoolSelect.append('<option value="' + results[i].CO_COID + '">' + 
      results[i].CO_NAME + '</option>'); 
    });
```

}

Comment: Given that this was an issue with using an incorrect selector, the question is subject to being closed as a typo.